# TypeError: swal is not a function in SweetAlert.js in angularjs using ngSweetAlert

Tags: angularjs, sweetalert

I have tried the ngSweetAlert in my angular app. and when ever itry to used the SweetAlert.swal() Error occured im my developers tool TypeError: swal is not a function.

snippet.

```
(function() {
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('iCheckMobile', ['oitozero.ngSweetAlert']);
var BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/';

app.controller('MobileCntrlr', ['$http', '$scope', '$window', '$location', '$interval', '$timeout', 'iCheckMobileFactory', '$filter', 'SweetAlerts', function($http, $scope, $window, $location, $interval, $timeout, iCheckMobileFactory, $filter, SweetAlerts) {
    var mbleCntrl = this;
```

.
.
.
///area where i used ngSweetAlert

```
var forceSubmitExam = function() {
        // $window.confirm('Submiting exammination automatically');
        SweetAlerts.swal('Submitting Examination Automatically', 'You have not enough time', 'success');
        var submitInfo = {
            'answers': JSON.stringify(mbleCntrl.answers),
            'student_id': mbleCntrl.studentDetail.id,
            'subject_slug': mbleCntrl.subject_slug,
            'subject_id': subject_id
        };
        $http.post(BASE_URL + 'mobile/examination/submit', submitInfo)
            .success(function(response) {
                mbleCntrl.answers = '';
                console.log(response);
            })
            .error(function() {
                $window.confirm('Error on submitting the examination!');
            })
    };
```

SweetAlert.js

```
    angular.module('oitozero.ngSweetAlert', [])
.factory('SweetAlerts', [ '$rootScope', function ( $rootScope ) {
    var swal = window.swal;
    //public methods
    var self = {
        swal: function ( arg1, arg2, arg3 ) {
            $rootScope.$evalAsync(function(){
                if( typeof(arg2) === 'function' ) {
                    swal( arg1, function(isConfirm){
                        $rootScope.$evalAsync( function(){
                            arg2(isConfirm);
                        });
                    }, arg3 );
                } else {
                    swal( arg1, arg2, arg3 );
                }
            });
        },
        success: function(title, message) {
            $rootScope.$evalAsync(function(){
                swal( title, message, 'success' );
            });
        },
        error: function(title, message) {
            $rootScope.$evalAsync(function(){
                swal( title, message, 'error' );
            });
        },
        warning: function(title, message) {
            $rootScope.$evalAsync(function(){
                swal( title, message, 'warning' );
            });
        },
        info: function(title, message) {    
            $rootScope.$evalAsync(function(){
                swal( title, message, 'info' );
            });
        }
    };

    return self;
}]);
```

I think there is something wrong with it, can you help me guys, ^^ totally novice in angular. thanks.

Answer (score 8):

First Include Js File

```
<script src="components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Than Include Angular File

```
<script src="components/angular-sweetalert/SweetAlert.js"></script>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simply making sure you're calling the files in the correct order did the trick. The docs imply the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue. Here is how fixed it.

You need to include one more Sweetalert file.

```
 !function (e, t) { function n() { var e = '<div class="sweet-overlay"  tabIndex="-1"></div><div class="sweet-alert" tabIndex="-1"><div class="icon error"><span class="x-mark"><span class="line left"></span><span class="line right"></span></span></div><div class="icon warning"> <span class="body"></span> <span class="dot"></span> </div> <div class="icon info"></div> <div class="icon success"> <span class="line tip"></span> <span class="line long"></span> <div class="placeholder"></div> <div class="fix"></div> </div> <div class="icon custom"></div> <h2>Title</h2><p>Text</p><button class="cancel" tabIndex="2">Cancel</button><button class="confirm" tabIndex="1">OK</button></div>', n = t.createElement("div"); n.innerHTML = e, t.body.appendChild(n) } function o(t) { var n = m(), o = n.querySelector("h2"), r = n.querySelector("p"), a = n.querySelector("button.cancel"), c = n.querySelector("button.confirm"); if (o.innerHTML = b(t.title).split("\n").join("<br>"), r.innerHTML = b(t.text || "").split("\n").join("<br>"), t.text && w(r), x(n.querySelectorAll(".icon")), t.type) { for (var l = !1, s = 0; s < d.length; s++) if (t.type === d[s]) { l = !0; break } if (!l) return e.console.error("Unknown alert type: " + t.type), !1; var u = n.querySelector(".icon." + t.type); switch (w(u), t.type) { case "success": p(u, "animate"), p(u.querySelector(".tip"), "animateSuccessTip"), p(u.querySelector(".long"), "animateSuccessLong"); break; case "error": p(u, "animateErrorIcon"), p(u.querySelector(".x-mark"), "animateXMark"); break; case "warning": p(u, "pulseWarning"), p(u.querySelector(".body"), "pulseWarningIns"), p(u.querySelector(".dot"), "pulseWarningIns") } } if (t.imageUrl) { var f = n.querySelector(".icon.custom"); f.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + t.imageUrl + ")", w(f); var g = 80, y = 80; if (t.imageSize) { var v = t.imageSize.split("x")[0], h = t.imageSize.split("x")[1]; v && h ? (g = v, y = h, f.css({ width: v + "px", height: h + "px" })) : e.console.error("Parameter imageSize expects value with format WIDTHxHEIGHT, got " + t.imageSize) } f.setAttribute("style", f.getAttribute("style") + "width:" + g + "px; height:" + y + "px") } n.setAttribute("data-has-cancel-button", t.showCancelButton), t.showCancelButton ? a.style.display = "inline-block" : x(a), t.cancelButtonText && (a.innerHTML = b(t.cancelButtonText)), t.confirmButtonText && (c.innerHTML = b(t.confirmButtonText)), c.style.backgroundColor = t.confirmButtonColor, i(c, t.confirmButtonColor), n.setAttribute("data-allow-ouside-click", t.allowOutsideClick); var S = t.doneFunction ? !0 : !1; n.setAttribute("data-has-done-function", S) } function r(e, t) { e = String(e).replace(/[^0-9a-f]/gi, ""), e.length < 6 && (e = e[0] + e[0] + e[1] + e[1] + e[2] + e[2]), t = t || 0; var n = "#", o, r; for (r = 0; 3 > r; r++) o = parseInt(e.substr(2 * r, 2), 16), o = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(0, o + o * t), 255)).toString(16), n += ("00" + o).substr(o.length); return n } function a(e) { var t = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(e); return t ? parseInt(t[1], 16) + ", " + parseInt(t[2], 16) + ", " + parseInt(t[3], 16) : null } function i(e, t) { var n = a(t); e.style.boxShadow = "0 0 2px rgba(" + n + ", 0.8), inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)" } function c() { var e = m(); B(g(), 10), w(e), p(e, "showSweetAlert"), v(e, "hideSweetAlert"), O = t.activeElement; var n = e.querySelector("button.confirm"); n.focus(), setTimeout(function () { p(e, "visible") }, 500) } function l() { var n = m(); T(g(), 5), T(n, 5), v(n, "showSweetAlert"), p(n, "hideSweetAlert"), v(n, "visible"); var o = n.querySelector(".icon.success"); v(o, "animate"), v(o.querySelector(".tip"), "animateSuccessTip"), v(o.querySelector(".long"), "animateSuccessLong"); var r = n.querySelector(".icon.error"); v(r, "animateErrorIcon"), v(r.querySelector(".x-mark"), "animateXMark"); var a = n.querySelector(".icon.warning"); v(a, "pulseWarning"), v(a.querySelector(".body"), "pulseWarningIns"), v(a.querySelector(".dot"), "pulseWarningIns"), e.onkeydown = A, t.onclick = I, O && O.focus(), M = void 0 } function s() { var e = m(); e.style.marginTop = k(m()) } var u = ".sweet-alert", f = ".sweet-overlay", d = ["error", "warning", "info", "success"], m = function () { return t.querySelector(u) }, g = function () { return t.querySelector(f) }, y = function (e, t) { return new RegExp(" " + t + " ").test(" " + e.className + " ") }, p = function (e, t) { y(e, t) || (e.className += " " + t) }, v = function (e, t) { var n = " " + e.className.replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, " ") + " "; if (y(e, t)) { for (; n.indexOf(" " + t + " ") >= 0;) n = n.replace(" " + t + " ", " "); e.className = n.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") } }, b = function (e) { var n = t.createElement("div"); return n.appendChild(t.createTextNode(e)), n.innerHTML }, h = function (e) { e.style.opacity = "", e.style.display = "block" }, w = function (e) { if (e && !e.length) return h(e); for (var t = 0; t < e.length; ++t) h(e[t]) }, S = function (e) { e.style.opacity = "", e.style.display = "none" }, x = function (e) { if (e && !e.length) return S(e); for (var t = 0; t < e.length; ++t) S(e[t]) }, C = function (e, t) { for (var n = t.parentNode; null !== n;) { if (n === e) return !0; n = n.parentNode } return !1 }, k = function (e) { e.style.left = "-9999px", e.style.display = "block"; var t = e.clientHeight, n = parseInt(getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue("padding"), 10); return e.style.left = "", e.style.display = "none", "-" + parseInt(t / 2 + n) + "px" }, B = function (e, t) { if (+e.style.opacity < 1) { t = t || 16, e.style.opacity = 0, e.style.display = "block"; var n = +new Date, o = function () { e.style.opacity = +e.style.opacity + (new Date - n) / 100, n = +new Date, +e.style.opacity < 1 && setTimeout(o, t) }; o() } }, T = function (e, t) { t = t || 16, e.style.opacity = 1; var n = +new Date, o = function () { e.style.opacity = +e.style.opacity - (new Date - n) / 100, n = +new Date, +e.style.opacity > 0 ? setTimeout(o, t) : e.style.display = "none" }; o() }, E = function (n) { if (MouseEvent) { var o = new MouseEvent("click", { view: e, bubbles: !1, cancelable: !0 }); n.dispatchEvent(o) } else if (t.createEvent) { var r = t.createEvent("MouseEvents"); r.initEvent("click", !1, !1), n.dispatchEvent(r) } else t.createEventObject ? n.fireEvent("onclick") : "function" == typeof n.onclick && n.onclick() }, q = function (t) { "function" == typeof t.stopPropagation ? (t.stopPropagation(), t.preventDefault()) : e.event && e.event.hasOwnProperty("cancelBubble") && (e.event.cancelBubble = !0) }, O, I, A, M; e.sweetAlert = e.swal = function () { function n(e) { var t = e.keyCode || e.which; if (-1 !== [9, 13, 32, 27].indexOf(t)) { for (var n = e.target || e.srcElement, o = -1, r = 0; r < h.length; r++) if (n === h[r]) { o = r; break } 9 === t ? (n = -1 === o ? v : o === h.length - 1 ? h[0] : h[o + 1], q(e), n.focus(), i(n, u.confirmButtonColor)) : (n = 13 === t || 32 === t ? -1 === o ? v : void 0 : 27 !== t || b.hidden || "none" === b.style.display ? void 0 : b, void 0 !== n && E(n, e)) } } function a(e) { var t = e.target || e.srcElement, n = e.relatedTarget, o = y(f, "visible"); if (o) { var r = -1; if (null !== n) { for (var a = 0; a < h.length; a++) if (n === h[a]) { r = a; break } -1 === r && t.focus() } else M = t } } var u = { title: "", text: "", type: null, allowOutsideClick: !1, showCancelButton: !1, closeOnConfirm: !0, closeOnCancel: !0, confirmButtonText: "OK", confirmButtonColor: "#AEDEF4", cancelButtonText: "Cancel", imageUrl: null, imageSize: null }; if (void 0 === arguments[0]) return e.console.error("sweetAlert expects at least 1 attribute!"), !1; switch (typeof arguments[0]) { case "string": u.title = arguments[0], u.text = arguments[1] || "", u.type = arguments[2] || ""; break; case "object": if (void 0 === arguments[0].title) return e.console.error('Missing "title" argument!'), !1; u.title = arguments[0].title, u.text = arguments[0].text || u.text, u.type = arguments[0].type || u.type, u.allowOutsideClick = arguments[0].allowOutsideClick || u.allowOutsideClick, u.showCancelButton = void 0 !== arguments[0].showCancelButton ? arguments[0].showCancelButton : u.showCancelButton, u.closeOnConfirm = void 0 !== arguments[0].closeOnConfirm ? arguments[0].closeOnConfirm : u.closeOnConfirm, u.closeOnCancel = void 0 !== arguments[0].closeOnCancel ? arguments[0].closeOnCancel : u.closeOnCancel, u.confirmButtonText = u.showCancelButton ? "Confirm" : u.confirmButtonText, u.confirmButtonText = arguments[0].confirmButtonText || u.confirmButtonText, u.confirmButtonColor = arguments[0].confirmButtonColor || u.confirmButtonColor, u.cancelButtonText = arguments[0].cancelButtonText || u.cancelButtonText, u.imageUrl = arguments[0].imageUrl || u.imageUrl, u.imageSize = arguments[0].imageSize || u.imageSize, u.doneFunction = arguments[1] || null; break; default: return e.console.error('Unexpected type of argument! Expected "string" or "object", got ' + typeof arguments[0]), !1 } o(u), s(), c(); for (var f = m(), d = function (e) { var t = e.target || e.srcElement, n = "confirm" === t.className, o = y(f, "visible"), a = u.doneFunction && "true" === f.getAttribute("data-has-done-function"); switch (e.type) { case "mouseover": n && (e.target.style.backgroundColor = r(u.confirmButtonColor, -.04)); break; case "mouseout": n && (e.target.style.backgroundColor = u.confirmButtonColor); break; case "mousedown": n && (e.target.style.backgroundColor = r(u.confirmButtonColor, -.14)); break; case "mouseup": n && (e.target.style.backgroundColor = r(u.confirmButtonColor, -.04)); break; case "focus": var i = f.querySelector("button.confirm"), c = f.querySelector("button.cancel"); n ? c.style.boxShadow = "none" : i.style.boxShadow = "none"; break; case "click": if (n && a && o) u.doneFunction(!0), u.closeOnConfirm && l(); else if (a && o) { var s = String(u.doneFunction).replace(/\s/g, ""), d = "function(" === s.substring(0, 9) && ")" !== s.substring(9, 10); d && u.doneFunction(!1), u.closeOnCancel && l() } else l() } }, g = f.querySelectorAll("button"), p = 0; p < g.length; p++) g[p].onclick = d, g[p].onmouseover = d, g[p].onmouseout = d, g[p].onmousedown = d, g[p].onfocus = d; I = t.onclick, t.onclick = function (e) { var t = e.target || e.srcElement, n = f === t, o = C(f, e.target), r = y(f, "visible"), a = "true" === f.getAttribute("data-allow-ouside-click"); !n && !o && r && a && l() }; var v = f.querySelector("button.confirm"), b = f.querySelector("button.cancel"), h = f.querySelectorAll("button:not([type=hidden])"); A = e.onkeydown, e.onkeydown = n, v.onblur = a, b.onblur = a, e.onfocus = function () { e.setTimeout(function () { void 0 !== M && (M.focus(), M = void 0) }, 0) } }, function () { "complete" === t.readyState || "interactive" === t.readyState ? n() : t.addEventListener ? t.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function e() { t.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", arguments.callee, !1), n() }, !1) : t.attachEvent && t.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function () { "complete" === t.readyState && (t.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", arguments.callee), n()) }) }() }(window, document);
```

Copy the above js & create a file with some relative name & include it before the sweet-alert.min.js.

Reload the page & call. Error gone. :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @user3486758. Glad to hear that :)

Comment: Where does that code come from? copy paste of unproven code is a malpractice.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Did you add sweetalert dependency(sweet-alert.js AND sweet-alert.css)?
If you didn't ,you should add it.(ngSweetAlert rely on [sweetalert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert))